# Left join when left table does not have all group by columns

Tags: sql, hive

I'm finding it a bit difficult to word the question precisely.

So, to simplify: I have two tables, call them `event_type` and `player_events`. The first table is a list of event types (strings), call the column `event_type.name`.

`player_events` is a list of individual player events. Some players may be missing some events, and events may occur multiple times for the same player. So `player_events` has relevant columns `player_events.player_id` and `player_events.event_type_name`, among other columns dealing with creation time and so on, but the latter are irrelevant.

I want a player-event-type count, including the zeros. I need to distinguish between different event types for each player. So in the end I should get something like this:

`player_id   event_type_name     player_event_count
0           LoginEvent          1
0           ProfileChangedEvent 0
1           LoginEvent          5
1           ProfileChangedEvent 1
...`

I was thinking of left joining the `event_type` table with the `player_events` table and somehow grouping on `player_events.player_id` and `player_events.event_type_name`, but I can't get this to work.

Something analogous to this misses the zeros:

`select player_id, event_type_name, count(event_type_name) as player_event_count
from player_events
group by player_id, event_type_name`

How is something like this best done?

Comment: Remove event_type_name from the GROUP BY.

Comment: I need to group by event type names, since I want to distinguish between, say, a LoginEvent and a ProfileChangedEvent.

Comment: Well, since you don't select that column, I jumped to conclusions.

Comment: You're right, I fixed it.

Comment: Explanation are O.K. but there is nothing like a good data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `PLAYER` table (parent of `PLAYER_EVENT_TYPES`, in which `PLAYER_ID` is the primary key), a good way to do it would be this:

```
select p.player_id, et.event_type_name, count(*) as player_event_count
from event_type et 
     cross join players p 
     left join player_events pe on pe.player_id = p.player_id and pe.event_type_name = et.event_type_name
group by p.player_id, et.event_type_name;
```

#### Update based on no `PLAYER` table existing...

Since you don't have a `PLAYER` table, you could do this, instead:

```
SELECT pe.player_id,
       et.event_type_name,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN pe.event_type_name = et.event_type_name THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) cnt
FROM   player_events pe CROSS JOIN event_types et
GROUP BY pe.player_id, et.event_type_name
ORDER BY pe.player_id, et.event_type_name
```

(Sorry, I don't know "HIVE" you will have to use the equivalent of `CASE` in that database.)

I much prefer having a `PLAYER` table, as this is much less clear (to me).

Comment: I don't; the query is much more complicated than this because in actual fact the "tables" above are nested queries on the same table. But ``cross join`` seems exactly what I need. I'll try to make this work by getting a list of players first.

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer a style that was possible in the early nineties - before the CASE WHEN clause was available:

The trick here is to get all possible `player_id`-s in one (temporary) table, and all `event_type_name`-s in another table, and CROSS JOIN both together, to finally LEFT JOIN to the `player_events` table. Then count the `event_type_name`-s coming from the `player_events`table. A NULL occurrence of `event_type_name` simply does not count.

If you can rely on the fact that all `player_id`-s and all `event_type_name`-s are present in `player_events`, you do this:

```
WITH
-- input data for player_events, don't use in query
player_events(player_id,tm,event_type_name) AS (
          SELECT 0,TIME '00:01:01','LoginEvent'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '00:01:12','LoginEvent'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '00:01:12','LoginEvent'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '00:01:12','LoginEvent'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '00:01:12','LoginEvent'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '00:01:12','LoginEvent'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIME '00:01:12','ProfileChangedEvent'
)
-- real query starts here - replace the comma below with WITH
,
-- all distinct player_id-s from player_events
players AS (
SELECT DISTINCT player_id FROM player_events
)
,
-- all distinct event_type_name-s from player_events
all_event_types AS (
SELECT DISTINCT event_type_name FROM player_events
)
SELECT
  p.player_id
, a.event_type_name
, COUNT(e.event_type_name) AS player_event_count
FROM players         p
CROSS JOIN all_event_types a
LEFT JOIN player_events   e USING(player_id,event_type_name)
GROUP BY
  p.player_id
, a.event_type_name
ORDER BY
  p.player_id
;
```

If there are `player_id`-s or `event_type_name`-s that have no entry whatsoever in the `player_events` table, you will have to create a SELECT for both `player_id`-s and `event_type_name`-s that are guaranteed to return all possible occurrences, and replace the SELECT DISTINCT-s I used with those.

Good luck -

Marco